# Link each element of array in a document to the corresponding element in an array of another document with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, bson

Using MongoDB 4.2 and MongoDB Atlas to test aggregation pipelines.

I've got this **products** collection, containing documents with this schema:

```
 {
    "name": "TestProduct",
    "relatedList": [
      {id:ObjectId("someId")},
      {id:ObjectId("anotherId")}
    ]
 }
```

Then there's this **cities** collection, containing documents with this schema :

```
{
        "name": "TestCity",
        "instructionList": [
          { related_id: ObjectId("anotherId"), foo: bar},
          { related_id: ObjectId("someId"), foo: bar}
          { related_id: ObjectId("notUsefulId"), foo: bar}
          ...
        ]
 }
```

My objective is to join both collections to output something like this (the operation is picking each related object from the instructionList in the city document to put it into the relatedList of the product document) :

```
{
        "name": "TestProduct",
        "relatedList": [
          { related_id: ObjectId("someId"), foo: bar},
          { related_id: ObjectId("anotherId"), foo: bar},
        ]
}
```

I tried using the $lookup operator for aggregation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019324/how-to-lookup-a-field-with-an-array-in-nested-subdocument-mongodb) :

```
$lookup:{
  from: 'cities',
  let: {rId:'$relatedList._id'},
  pipeline: [
         {
           $match: {
             $expr: {
               $eq: ["$instructionList.related_id", "$$rId"]
             }
           }
         },
  ]
}
```

But it's not working, I'm a bit lost with this complex pipeline syntax.

## Edit

By using unwind on both arrays :

```
    { 
         {$unwind: "$relatedList"},
         {$lookup:{
             from: "cities",
             let: { "rId": "$relatedList.id" },
             pipeline: [
        
                {$unwind:"$instructionList"},
                {$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$instructionList.related_id","$$rId"]}}},

             ],
             as:"instructionList",
         }},

         {$group: {
             _id: "$_id",
             instructionList: {$addToSet:"$instructionList"}

          }}
}
```

I am able to achieve what I want, however,
I'm not getting a clean result at all :

```
{
 "name": "TestProduct",
 instructionList: [
    [
      {
        "name": "TestCity",
        "instructionList": {
         "related_id":ObjectId("someId")
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "TestCity",
        "instructionList": {
         "related_id":ObjectId("anotherId")
        }
      }
    ]
 ]
}
```

How can I group everything to be as clean as stated for my original question ?
Again, I'm completely lost with the Aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the operation is picking each related object from the instructionList in the city document to put it into the relatedList of the product document)

Given an example document on `cities` collection:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("5e4a22a08c54c8e2380b853b"),
  "name": "TestCity",
  "instructionList": [
    {"related_id": "a", "foo": "x"},
    {"related_id": "b", "foo": "y"},
    {"related_id": "c", "foo": "z"}
]}
```

and an example document on `products` collection:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("5e45cdd8e8d44a31a432a981"),
  "name": "TestProduct",
  "relatedList": [
    {"id": "a"},
    {"id": "b"}
]}
```

You can achieve try using the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {"$lookup":{
        "from": "cities", 
        "let": { "rId": "$relatedList.id" }, 
        "pipeline": [
            {"$unwind":"$instructionList"},
            {"$match":{
                "$expr":{
                    "$in":["$instructionList.related_id", "$$rId"]
                }
            }
        }], 
        "as":"relatedList",
    }}, 
    {"$project":{
        "name":"$name",
        "relatedList":{
            "$map":{
                "input":"$relatedList",
                "as":"x",
                "in":{
                    "related_id":"$$x.instructionList.related_id",
                    "foo":"$$x.instructionList.foo"
                }                
            }
        }
    }}
]);
```

To get a result as the following:

```
{  "_id": ObjectId("5e45cdd8e8d44a31a432a981"),
   "name": "TestProduct",
   "relatedList": [
          {"related_id": "a", "foo": "x"},
          {"related_id": "b", "foo": "y"}
]}
```

The above is tested in MongoDB v4.2.x.

> But it's not working, I'm a bit lost with this complex pipeline syntax.

The reason why it's slightly complex here is because you have an array `relatedList` and also an array of subdocuments `instructionList`. When you refer to `instructionList.related_id` (which could mean multiple values) with `$eq` operator, the pipeline doesn't know which one to match.

In the pipeline above, I've added [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to turn `instructionList` into multiple single documents. Afterward, using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to express a match of single value of `instructionList.related_id` in array `relatedList`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not working, the problem is with the $relatedList array which can't be evaluated unless it's being unwinded

Comment: @SquixDev, I noticed that you've changed the `products` collection `relatedList` array of IDs to array of documents with `id` field. I've updated the answer to reflect your schema validation.

Comment: Tested again, it's not working. It's simply populate relatedList with each instruction of InstructionList, without checking if that instruction is concerning one of the related Element of the relatedList of the product. (Maybe I'm not clear on what I'm trying to achieve ?)

Comment: @SquixDev, updated the answer to reflect your updated question

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to $unwind the arrays in order to lookup the relation, then $group to recollect them.  Perhaps something like:

```
.aggregeate([
    {$unwind:"relatedList"},
    {$lookup:{
         from:"cities",
         let:{rId:"$relatedList.id"}
         pipeline:[
             {$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$instructionList.related_id", "$$rId"]}}},
             {$unwind:"$instructionList"},
             {$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$instructionList.related_id", "$$rId"]}}},
             {$project:{_id:0, instruction:"$instructionList"}}
         ],
         as: "lookedup"
     }},
     {$addFields: {"relatedList.foo":"$lookedup.0.instruction.foo"}},
     {$group: {
                _id:"$_id",
                root: {$first:"$$ROOT"},
                relatedList:{$push:"$relatedList"}
     }},
     {$addFields:{"root.relatedList":"$relatedList"}},
     {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$root"}}
])
```

A little about each stage:

- $unwind duplicates the entire document for each element of the array,
  replace the array with the single element
- $lookup can then consider each element separately.  The stages in $lookup.pipeline:
  a. $match so we only unwind the document with matching ID
  b. $unwind the array so we can consider individual elements
  c. repeat the $match so we are only left with matching elements (hopefully just 1)
- $addFields assigns the `foo` field retrieved from the lookup to the object from `relatedList`
- $group collects together all of the documents with the same _id (i.e. that were unwound from a single original document), stores the first as 'root', and pushes all of the relatedList elements back into an array
- $addFields moves the relatedList in to root
- $replaceRoot returns the `root`, which should now be the original document with the matching `foo` added to each `relatedList` element